# how use firebase android for multiple id application

Tags: android, firebase

I have an application that is different for each user, id application is different for each user, so idApplication is dynamic. My problem is that json retrieved from firebase is linked to a single application id. How can I use one file json for all the applications I generate dynamically?

_______édit ____

I don't know thé application id, this application id is modified on a filé jenkins.properties on my project Android, and when jenkins générate New apk it do it with thé New id

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on `google-services.json` and associated gradle plugin you can dynamically create `FirebaseApp` using something like following (I have this in dagger module)

```
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(someApplicationId)
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
            .setStorageBucket(storageBucket)
            .build();

    firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "MyApp");
```

Comment: what is databaseurl ?, storagebukket ? this is what we found in the file json ?

Comment: yes, they'll be in `google-services.json` for your various apps (you'll need to create separate `apps` in Firebase console and `google-services.json` you download will contain info for all of them).  If you're not using firebase storage for example you can also remove that line.

Comment: Ok thank you for your response i will try your solution

Comment: Remember to remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line from your gradle file if you're taking this approach.

Comment: I cant use your solution because 
I dont know thé application id, this application id is modified on a filé jenkins.properties on m'y projet Android, and when jenkins générate New apk it do it with thé New id

Comment: Can you not populate it dynamically with the application id used?  For example, use `resValue` in your build.gradle to set string resource (based on `project.property()` value for example)....and then use that string in the code above.

Comment: but they dont want to create manually the application with the new id on the firebase console,

Comment: they have a process on the back office who do thinks dynamycally